# How to make a Lookup Field trigger a reRender to make other fields visible?

Tags: apex, javascript

I have an APEX page with a few fields and some buttons. Initially, the first field (a lookup field) is the only one that is shown. I would like to be able to show the other fields once the user has selected a value from the lookup window.

Currently, I am using `rendered={!isFieldSet == true}` in the fields I want to hide until later, but I am unable to update this value and get the fields to appear. I am currently using a javascript `onchange` method to call the controller method to set the `isFieldSet` value. But when I examine the property from javascript, it does not see the change to the `isFieldSet`, I guess because the page has not been reloaded? I am wondering what the standard way to get this sort of thing to work is. Currently I am trying to reload the page using url arguments, but the lookup field value is not coming through to the backend.

Here is some code for reference.

```
    <apex:inputField value="{!objectReference.propertyName}" required="true" onchange="actionpropertyValueChanged();">
```

Here is the code for hiding a section:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!isFieldSet == true}" id="daySelectorBlock">
         ...
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: There a two things that you might have missed 1)In your Action function or Action Support use Rerender attribute to rerender the Pageblock 2)The boolean must be a getter and setter and you must set the boolean in the controller method .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[apex:actionSupport](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) can be used to rerender a component via AJAX when a change is made to the inputField.

```
<apex:actionStatus startText="Wait." stopText="" id="inputFieldActionStatus"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!objectReference.propertyName}" required="true" >
     <apex:actionSupport action="{!someControllerMethod}" status="inputFieldActionStatus" 
         event="onclick" rerender="daySelectorBlock">
         // You might want an apex:Param here to pass the inputField value back via ajax
     </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputField>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!isFieldSet}" id="daySelectorBlock">
    //...
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

After the AJAX call to the server the pageBlockSectionItem should render if `isFieldSet` is set to true via the method `someControllerMethod`.

Comment: Super. That has done the trick. I had actually tried to add something like that, but I used actionFunction instead of actionSupport... Thanks!

Comment: Just to caveat one thing - if the daySelectorBlock wasn't rendered when the page was originally displayed, then a rerender of it will have no effect.  You need to wrap this inside a component that is always rendered and then rerender that.  This is explained better at: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html